# Is there a way to assign unique values to the names that have cosine similarity higher than 0.8?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, nlp

I am able to calculate the cosine similarity between different names.
After that i want to assign unique values to those names that have similarity > 0.8

I have tried creating a dictionary containing names as key and assigned unique value as values

```
dict1 = {}

ui = 0

def word2vec(word):
    from collections import Counter
    from math import sqrt
    cw = Counter(word)
    sw = set(cw)
    lw = sqrt(sum(c*c for c in cw.values()))
    return cw, sw, lw
def cosdis(v1, v2):
    common = v1[1].intersection(v2[1])
    return sum(v1[0][ch]*v2[0][ch] for ch in common)/v1[2]/v2[2]
list1 = list(df['Name'].unique())
for m in list1:
    for i in range(0, len(list1)):   
        vec1 = word2vec(m)
        vec2 = word2vec(list1[i])
        x = cosdis(vec1,vec2)
        if(x >=.80):
            dict1[m, list[i]] = 'A' + str(ui)                       
        else:
            pass
        ui = ui + 1
```

I would like all similar names to have same value in the dictionary.